# logical error in singly linked list code c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

For the following code, the result that I'm aiming for is 4-->5-->, however the result that is outputted is only 4-->

For context, I'm trying to implement a singly linked list using structure and functions only in c++.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
node* head = NULL;
void insert(int val)
{

    node* n = new node();
    n->data = val;


    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = n;
    }
    else
    {
        node* temp = head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp = n;
    }
}
void display()
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"UNDERFLOW ! LINKED LIST IS EMPTY !"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"LINKED LIST!"<<endl;
        node* temp = head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<"-->";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    insert(4);
    insert(5);
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look real carefully at the append logic in `insert`.  What's the value of `temp` when you assign `n`?

Comment: , thank you, the comment was super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As rightly pointed by @StephenNewell, you have a bug in the insert function.

Also in C++, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Change the below code in `insert()`:

```
node* temp = head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp = n;
```

to:

```
node* temp = head;
while (temp->next != nullptr)
{
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = n;
```

Comment: it was really helpful, thankyou.

Comment: @jdsingh, if my answer was helpful, do consider up voting :-)

Answer (score 0):

You question is `temp` is a temporary variable, and you just change the value of the temporary variable every time but not the last node of the linked list.

If you want to change the value of the **pointer**, you need the **pointer of the pointer** or
You should change to

```
while(temp->next != NULL)
{
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = n;
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out.